# Как имитировать заход на сайт

Tags: javascript, http

Допустим есть сайт, я там зарегистрирован:

- *user1*
- *password*

Также есть веб-сервер, как мне с помощью яваскрипта, имитировать заход на сайт один раз в два часа ? Если c помощью [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) нельзя, то подойдёт и [php](/questions/tagged/php)

Comment: Можешь попробовать использовать selenium и phantomJS

Comment: Если владешь JS то смотри в сторону NIGTMARE.JS.
На чистом PHP можно зайти через CURL.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что вход на сайт - это отправка логина и пароля на сервер. Можно повесить отправку этих данных на клик по submit, который будет срабатывать через какое-то время после загрузки страницы.

Этот же клик перезагрузит страницу, и данные формы автоматически заполнятся по событию window.onload. А если отправка данных осуществляется ajax'ом, то можно принудительно перезагружать страницу:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 var log = document.getElementById('login');
 var pass = document.getElementById('pass');
 
 log.value = 'Вася Пупкин';
 pass.value = 'qwerty';
}

var sec=10;
function Sec() {
    document.getElementById('sec').innerHTML=sec;
    var sub = document.getElementById('sub');
    sec--;
    if(sec < 0) {
   sub.click();
      location.reload(); // на случай ajax'а
    }
   setTimeout('Sec()',1000);
}
 
Sec();
```

```css
#sec {
   color:red;
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<form action="" type="post">
<input type="text" id="login" /><br /><br />
<input type="password" id="pass" /><br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" value="Войти" /><br /><br />
</form>

Имитация входа произойдет через
<span id="sec" name="sec">10</span> секунд
```

Comment: Эм.. А как же CORS?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а что CORS? Это же простой запрос. По идее живой пользователь может безо всякой имитации заходить на сайт каждые 2 часа - кто ему запретит? )

Comment: @humster_spb я со своего сервера, хочу программно посетить другой сайт, с известными учетными данными

Comment: @stack-it, ну, cron тогда используйте, чо - https://ru.hostings.info/schools/cron.html

Comment: cron и (curl или wget)

Comment: хорошо, а как сайт я посещу, покажите пример какой то